# Setup code coverage for Go in Azure DevOps

Tags: go, azure-devops, code-coverage

It is not clear for me how code coverage works in Azure DevOps for my Golang project.
My expertation is to see something like this:

[image]

#### Missing Code Coverage

I'm confused, because I see this hint "Setup code coverage":

[image]

But in the tab "Code Coverage" is a generated html report:

[image]

#### Warning in Task "Publish code coverage results"

I got this warning in the task "Publish code coverage results"

`##[warning]Ignoring coverage report directory with Html content as we are auto-generating Html content`

But when I disable the html generation with `disable.coverage.autogenerate: 'false'` no report is display under the tab "Code Coverage", only the message "Code coverage report cannot be rendered as report HTML was not found. Please verify that "Report Directory" containing an HTML report was specified when publishing code coverage."

#### Azure Pipeline

This is my pipeline:

```
trigger: 
 - master

pool:
   vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  GOBIN:  '$(GOPATH)/bin'
  GOPATH: '$(system.defaultWorkingDirectory)/gopath'
  disable.coverage.autogenerate: 'false'

steps: 

- script: |
    echo '##vso[task.prependpath]$(GOBIN)'
    echo '##vso[task.prependpath]$(GOROOT)/bin'

- task: GoTool@0
  inputs:
    version: '1.14.2'
- task: Go@0
  inputs:
    command: 'get'
    arguments: '-d ./...'
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'

- script: |
    go get github.com/jstemmer/go-junit-report
    go get github.com/axw/gocov/gocov
    go get github.com/AlekSi/gocov-xml
    go test -v -coverprofile=coverage.txt -covermode count ./... 2>&1 | go-junit-report > report.xml
    gocov convert coverage.txt > coverage.json
    gocov-xml < coverage.json > coverage.xml
    mkdir coverage
  workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
  displayName: 'Run unit test'

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testRunner: JUnit
    testResultsFiles: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/report.xml

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: Cobertura 
    pathToSources: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    summaryFileLocation: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/coverage.xml
    reportDirectory: $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/**/coverage
    failIfCoverageEmpty: true
```

Full log: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/dhcgn/682dd6027d8d0703cb4dc6d5ae2fbead/raw/9d2bb96d1d8a0721335d56a121a5eed254ac014f/pipeline.log

Comment: Hi the document `Setup code coverage` has not been updated. What you saw there was the old version of build summary page. Check out below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code coverage report you expect to see on the build summary is the old build pipeline UI page.

Now Azure devops services has implemented the new [multi-stage pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/multi-stage-pipelines-experience?view=azure-devops) UI page. Code coverage report is moved to the **Code Coverage** tab as what you see now.

The build Summary page you expect to see in above screenshot is no longer available, for the this feature toggle which allows to switch back to the old build pipeline UI page has been removed. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2020/sprint-168-update#multi-stage-pipelines-ga).

However, you can still see the old pipeline UI page in Azure DevOps Server 2019/TFS 2018 /TFS 2017.